# Can I get a conversion during template argument deduction?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this code here:

```cpp
#pragma once
using uInt = size_t;

template<uInt id> class idType {};
template<typename T> class typeId {};

#define Generate_Type_To_ID_Mapping(id, t)                          \
class t;                                                            \
template<>class idType<id> { public: using type = t; };             \
template<>class typeId<t> { public: operator uInt() { return val; } \
    typeId() = default;                                             \
    typeId(typeId const&) = delete;                                 \
    typeId& operator=(typeId const&) = delete;                      \
    typeId(typeId&&) = delete;                                      \
    typeId& operator=(typeId&&) = delete;                           \
    static constexpr uInt val = id;                                 \
};

Generate_Type_To_ID_Mapping(0, Entity);
Generate_Type_To_ID_Mapping(1, RectComponent);
Generate_Type_To_ID_Mapping(2, ConstraintComponent);
Generate_Type_To_ID_Mapping(3, TextComponent);
```

Which is a macro which manufacture 2 templates specializations for every given set of `<size_t, T>`, one template does conversion from type to index, the other do conversion from index to type.
They are called like this:

```
// type to index:
typeId<RectComponent>()  // the conversion operator returns 
                         // the value mapped to this type
// index to type:
idType<2>::type          // type is an alias to the mapped type
```

they work fine by themselves, but if I try to put one inside the other like so `idType<typeId<RectComponent>()>::type` the code won't compile, and I suspect this is because template argument deduction is not attempting any conversion (`typeId<>()` relies on `operator uInt()`)

There is some way for me to make it so `operator uInt()` is considered as an option during Template argument deduction?

Comment: Mark the operator and constructor as `constexpr` or use `typeId<RectComponent>::val`

Comment: Oh, right. You also need to use `idType<typeId<RectComponent>{}>::type` if you mark them constexpr. Notice the `{}` instead of `()`.

Comment: unfortunately the {} make the autoformat go crazy, so that it will basically explode it like `typename idType < typeId<T>{} > ::type`, also I really wanted the () for consistency with `typeId<RectComponent>()`... so I get it can't ge done. Thanks

Comment: You can use `typeId<ReactComponent>{}` everywhere for consistency. Arguably more idiomatic since you are constructing an object, and not calling a function.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that could be considered as a function declaration, a compiler parses as a function declaration. This is known as the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). `typeId<RectComponent>()` can be considered as a function declaration: nameless function that returns `typeId<RectComponent>` and takes to parameters.

That's why you get an error in `idType<typeId<RectComponent>()>::type`: a compiler tries to instantiate `idType` template with a function type as a template parameter.

The equivalent code is:

```
using T = typeId<RectComponent>();    // this line is OK, T is a function type
using Type = idType<T>::type;         // error is here
```

This equivalent code doesn't compile for exactly the same reason why

```
using Type = idType<typeId<RectComponent>()>::type;
```

doesn't compile.

---

What you want it this:

```
constexpr uInt id = typeId<RectComponent>();
using Type = idType<id>::type;
```

You can add extra parentheses to avoid ambiguity:

```
using Type = idType<(typeId<RectComponent>())>::type;
```

This works because `(typeId<RectComponent>())` is not a valid function declaration.

Of course `operator uInt()` should be marked `constexpr`:

```
constexpr operator uInt() { return val; }
```

See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TX6vHa).

Comment: that is definetly wrong, `using Type = idType<T>::type;` above doesn't compile

Comment: @MarcusAseth, of course it doesn't compile! It shouldn't. That's precisely why your original code doesn't compile. It's exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else attempting this, is worth mentioning the problem could be avoided altogether like this:

```cpp
template<typename T> class typeId_base {};
template<uInt id> class idType_base {};

template<uInt id>
using idType = typename idType_base<id>::type;
template<typename T>
inline constexpr uInt typeId = typeId_base<T>::val;

#define Generate_Type_To_ID_Mapping( id, t) \
class t;\
template<>class typeId_base<t> { public: static constexpr uInt val = id;};\
template<>class idType_base<id> { public: using type = t; };

Generate_Type_To_ID_Mapping(0, Entity);
Generate_Type_To_ID_Mapping(1, RectComponent);
Generate_Type_To_ID_Mapping(2, ConstraintComponent);
Generate_Type_To_ID_Mapping(3, TextComponent);
```

this allow for simply writing `idType<1>` and `typeId<RectComponent>` which is both simpler and uniform:

```cpp
int main()
{
    //from type to index
    std::cout << typeid(TextComponent).name() << " has ID " << typeId<TextComponent> << std::endl;

    //from index to type
    std::cout << typeid(idType<1>).name() << " has ID " << typeId<RectComponent> << std::endl;
}
```

or even `typeId<idType<1>>`